# need Java library -- A Local File Cache for Remote (eg S3) Files

Tags: java, caching, file-io, amazon-s3

My application requires a layer between Java and the filesystem to make transparent the fact that the filesystem only contains a subset of all the files (which are stored on S3). The layer has to do a lot of what normal file IO does, which is to open files, lock them for reading/writing, etc., but when opening it has to possibly download files and evict closed ones. Another feature I need is that if a file is locked for reading/writing, an open call can unlock the file and close the existing stream (ie, kick the other user off). Another is management of temporary files.

Is there anything remotely similar that is open source, or do I just have to roll up my sleeves? Should I start from scratch, or are there some hooks in java IO that I should tap?

Comment: It's a couple of years on, what did you do in the end?

Comment: @DavidNewcomb I wrote it. I kind of regretted it. The locking doesn't work across servers because the state isn't being tracked in a DB. But it works ok. We use it in production. Do you need it?

Comment: I was looking for something to cache File.listFiles() and stumbled on your project. It sounded interesting and so just wondered how it went.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you check [apache commons vfs](http://commons.apache.org/vfs/) Even if it's not exactly what you need, you may find useful ideas from it.

Answer (score 1):

This project aims to simplify creating a custom file system implementation for Java 7 NIO (java7-fs-base). The author has implemented a Dropbox FS (java7-fs-dropbox), and started work on S3 (java7-fs-amazon-s3). https://github.com/fge/java7-filesystems

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [AWS Storage Gateway](http://aws.amazon.com/storagegateway/) is worth considering in your case

> **Gateway-Cached Volumes:** You can store your primary data in Amazon S3, and retain your frequently accessed data locally. Gateway-Cached volumes provide substantial cost savings on primary storage, minimize the need to scale your storage on-premises, and retain low-latency access to your frequently accessed data.

Comment: It's an appliance, not a Java library. I ended up implementing my own, suffered a bunch of pain, made it too complicated (file locking, forceful stealing of locks, etc), realized elements of the approach are wrong, and now am putting off rewriting it.

Comment: @AleksandrDubinsky I knew, but maybe it would help in a buy vs. build situation.